# setTimeout doubling up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs with start and stop buttons I'm using as timers.  I create a json object to store some time variables in and some other stuff. When I click start, the timer works.  I'm setting one of the object's attributes equal to the timeout function `current_job = jobs[current_job_id];` then `current_job.t = setInterval(function(){...`.

When I click one of the other buttons though, the two setIntervals seem to double up. What am I doing wrong? Demo here:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/2d60722bb802bd1c3da5fe42cbc15442

And most of the code below:

```
var jobs = [];

$(".job").each(function(i){
    jobs[i] = {
        "start_time"    : false,
        "stop_time"     : false,
        "job_number"    : $(this).find("h1").text(),
        "time"          : 0,
        "chunk_id"      : false,
        "t"             : false,
    }
    $(this).attr('id', i);
})

$(".start_timer").click(function(){

    current_job_div = $(this).closest(".job");
    current_job_id = parseInt(current_job_div.attr("id"));
    current_job = jobs[current_job_id];


    current_job.t = setInterval(function(){
        current_job.time += 1;
        current_job_div.find(".time_spent").text(make_time(current_job.time));
    },1000);
});

$(".stop_timer").click(function(){

    current_job_div = $(this).closest(".job");
    current_job_id = parseInt(current_job_div.attr("id"));
    current_job = jobs[current_job_id];

    clearInterval(current_job.t);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures closures closures, see here: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#48

Working example of your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hkEga

(Edit: ^ although you do have a bug - try pressing start more than once :) )

Key code change:

```
current_job.t = (function (current_job, current_job_div) {
    return setInterval(function(){
        current_job.time += 1;
      current_job_div.find(".time_spent").text(make_time(current_job.time));
      },1000);
  }(current_job, current_job_div));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the use of *global variables*.

Thus every time the `Start` button is clicked the **same** global variable is changed.

Thus the code should be changed as:

```
var current_job_div = $(this).closest(".job");
var current_job_id = parseInt(current_job_div.attr("id"));
var current_job = jobs[current_job_id];
```

ie. create local variable rather than using global ones.